Secure an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API endoing with PFX file
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API. It was one endpoint that will be called by a 3rd party and there going to pass a PFX cert to prove it's them. I have no idea how to do this and tied myself in knots trying.
This is the endpoint in question:
   [HttpPost]
   [Authorize(Policy = "RequireCertificate")]
   public ActionResult Post(PostRequest postRequest)
   {
       return Ok("Message received");
   }

In Program.cs, I have:
// Add authorization policy for certificate-based endpoints
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireCertificate", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Certificate");
    });
});

// Configure Kestrel to use HTTPS with a PFX file
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(7241, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
        {
            // If one of these is wrong it will tell you when starting the projct
            httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(
                @"C:\localhost.pfx",  // Path to your PFX file
                "your_password"                  // PFX password
            );
        });
    });
});

I am trying to call this endpoint with postman, the settings are

If I call it with Postman, I get a http 403 - forbidden error, when I check the console, I can see in the header:

I am not sure if I am close or completely down the wrong path, I have tried removing code and certs  and got it the error message to change.

You are mixing up the client certificate that is used by the client to authenticate itself and the server side certificate to protect/secure the https traffic to/from the server. They are different certificates and you need both but they are not the same.

for .net API Yo dont have to write attribute for this.. API Authentication with Certificate will do same for you ! Client certs are used by browser already. If client is different than standart browser you ll need a bit more complex solution which i dont recommend if you dont have expertise on Certs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0

"builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel" is to configure the server certificate. But your demand is using client cerificate authentication. You need to manually add the auth scheme and check the cerificate (such as thumberprint) when the a certificate is received.
...
policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
...
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddCertificate(options =>
     {
         options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
         // Customize validation 
         options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
         {
             OnCertificateValidated = context =>
             {
                 // Extract client certificate
                 var clientCertificate = context.ClientCertificate;
                 // Add additional custom validation (e.g., check thumbprint, issuer)
                 if (clientCertificate.Thumbprint != "YOUR_EXPECTED_THUMBPRINT")
                 {
                     context.Fail("Client certificate thumbprint is invalid.");
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 }
                 // Add claims based on the certificate subject
                 var claims = new[]
                 {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, clientCertificate.Subject),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, clientCertificate.Subject)
                 };
                 context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                 context.Success();
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             },
             OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
             {
                 context.Fail("Invalid client certificate.");
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             }
         };
     });

